# Issue with initial render of components color

Tags: reactjs

I have a component rendering based on night mode (black) and day mode (blue). Which shifts modes based on a button press. The issue is for some reason it's rendering as white. After the initial render it goes back to the normal colors (black / blue), but initially it's white. I have useEffect looking for changes so shouldn't it run on the initial render and set the color to blue or black?

**This is what's providing the color. It is a function that's triggered when a button is pressed:**

```
const[isNightMode, setIsNightMode] = React.useState(false);

//INITIAL should be #55BAF1 (blue) but it's rendering as white
const [nightMode, setNightMode] = React.useState({
  background: "#FFFFFF",
  bannerText: "#FFFFFF",
  listText: "#000000",
  banner: "#55BAF1",
  inputBackground: "FFFFFF",
});

function switchNightMode(){
  const lightMode = {
      background: "#413250", 
      bannerText: "#413250",
      listText: "#FFFFFF", 
      banner: "#FFFFFF",
      inputBackground: "#465C68"
  }
  const darkMode = {
      background: "#FFFFFF" ,
      bannerText: "#FFFFFF" ,
      listText: "#000000",
      banner: "#55BAF1",
      inputBackground: "#465C68"
    }
  
  let currentMode;
  let currSavedBackground;
  
  if(isNightMode){
    setIsNightMode(false);
    currentMode = lightMode;
    currSavedBackground = "#413250";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = currSavedBackground;
  } else {
    setIsNightMode(true);
    currentMode = darkMode;
    currSavedBackground = "#FFFFFF";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = currSavedBackground;
  }
  
  setNightMode(currentMode);   
  
  //state is stored in case the app is closed and the user comes back
  localStorage.setItem("startupNightMode", JSON.stringify(currentMode));
}
```

**Use effect looks for changes:**

```
React.useEffect(() => {
   const sessionSettings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("startupNightMode")) || [];
   setNightMode(sessionSettings);
}, []);
```

**This is the component that is initially rendered as white. nightMode.banner is what's using the color:**

```
<Card style = {{marginBottom: 25, width: window.innerWidth/4, borderRadius: 30, backgroundColor: nightMode.banner, color: nightMode.bannerText, raised: true}}>
   <CardContent>
    <div style = {{display: 'flex', fontFamily: 'Work Sans', fontSize: 55}}>
      <text>{currDate}</text>
    </div>
    <text style = {{display: 'flex', fontFamily: 'Work Sans', fontSize: 45}}>{currTime}</text>
  </CardContent>
</Card>
```

Comment: useEffect runs for the first time after the initial render (equivalent with componentDidMount in a class based component) so on first render it uses the initial state you pass to `useState`

Comment: why do you use useContext for this? https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Comment: `useContext` is fairly standard for handling theme, it's true, but is still just a state value even if it is held in a separate hook; It will stilll be sensitive to the timing issues that the op is noting.

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` runs for the first time *after* the first render (equivalent to `componentDidMount` in a class component), so on first render it will use whatever initial value has been passed to `useState`.

In your case:

`const[isNightMode, setIsNightMode] = React.useState(false);`

You can either default to dark mode by passing `true` as the initial state:

`const[isNightMode, setIsNightMode] = React.useState(true);`

Or you can conditionally render the component to defer rendering until `useEffect` has run for the first time.

```
const[isNightMode, setIsNightMode] = React.useState(null)

React.useEffect(() => {
  const sessionSettings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("startupNightMode")) || [];
  setNightMode(sessionSettings);
}, []);

return (
  { isNightMode !== null && (
    <Card style={{ marginBottom: 25, width: window.innerWidth / 4, borderRadius: 30, backgroundColor: nightMode.banner, color: nightMode.bannerText, raised: true }}>
      <CardContent>
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', fontFamily: 'Work Sans', fontSize: 55 }}>
          <text>{currDate}</text>
        </div>
        <text style={{ display: 'flex', fontFamily: 'Work Sans', fontSize: 45 }}>{currTime}</text>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  )}
)
```

Comment: Sorry I just realized I missed a snippet of code which was the initial value passed into the hook. I've edited my code to include this, so the initial render should have been "#55BAF1" or blue. For some reason it initially renders in white

Comment: I tried the conditional rendering you suggested as well but it rendered in white again